# jQuery-UI resizable disabled is true but handles still shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

```
$('.box').resizable({
  disabled: true
});
```

and here's the CSS

```
.ui-resizable-disabled .ui-resizable-handle,
.ui-resizable-autohide .ui-resizable-handle {
  display: none;
}
```

According to the docs, when disabled is true, the `.ui-resizable-disabled` class gets added to the element. In my case the classes does not get added but the resizing is still disabled (meaning I can't resize by dragging the handles, but when disabled is false I can resize). When I check the generated HTML, `style="display:block"` was added to the handles. I'm not doing any show hide on them.

```
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="display: block; ">...</div>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8 from Google API. I'm also applying draggable to the same elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like its a default behavior. You can not resize though there is a handler. Anyways, you could hide the handler as:

```
//Dirty hack
$('div.ui-resizable-handle').hide();

//Somewhat effective solution
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({ disabled: true, handles: 'e' });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/W7HQ9/

Comment: This works for now. Thanks! If no one offers a solution or explanation that's more elegant I'll accept yours in a couple of days.

Comment: I suspect this is not meant to be default. If they are going to put inline styles on the handles why are there still styles to hide them in the stylesheet?

Comment: Giving the handles actually does the trick. $( "#resizable" ).resizable({ disabled: true, handles: 'e' });

Answer (score 0):

you can just hide the handle as below, this will only remove the handle image and you could still do the re-size..

```
$("#yourelementid").find('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon');
```